# Test with a static class both manipulated and not

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I am trying to run a Powermock test, with 2 methods for test.
The first method is a normal test without mocking anything, and works fine independently.
The second method uses PowerMockito.mockStatic(InetAddress.class) - where it manipulates the host address, and also works fine alone.
When I run both tests at the same time, one of the methods fails, depending on which was run first. The first test method is always successful, the 2nd one fails.

How can I avoid this issue?

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassForTest.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class TestForClassForTest{

    @Test
    public void test_is_ok() throws Exception {
        boolean internalLogging = ClassForTest.allowInternalLogging();
        Assert.assertTrue(internalLogging);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_nok() throws Exception {
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(InetAddress.class);
      PowerMockito.when(InetAddress.getLocalHost()).thenReturn(inetAddress);
      when(inetAddress.getHostAddress()).thenReturn("1.1.1.1");

      boolean internalLogging = ClassForTest.allowInternalLogging();
      Assert.assertFalse(internalLogging);
   }
}
```

The method "allowInternalLogging" determines, using InetAddress.getByName("domain") whether "domain" is reachable from the current network:

```
public final class ClassForTest {

    private static Boolean internalLogging;

    private ClassForTest() {
    }


    private static boolean inNetwork() {
        // By default no hosts should be found!
        boolean hostFound = false;

        try {
            // "Ping" the hosts by looking up the inetaddress
            final InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("some-hostname-which-we-know");

           // If the address is not null, we were able to lookup the
           // specified hostname.
           if (address != null) {
              hostFound = true;
           }

        } catch (final UnknownHostException ex) {
           // Host could not be found!
           hostFound = false;
        }

        return hostFound;
    }


    public static Boolean allowInternalLogging() {
        if (internalLogging == null) {
            try {
                internalLogging = inNetwork();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                internalLogging = false;
                LOGGER.debug("Could not determine logging granularity", e);
            }
        }
        return internalLogging;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I can provide the concrete example if needed" ... yes, please :)

Comment: @glytching done so

Comment: Would be useful to see the implementation of `ClassForTest.allowInternalLogging()` without this anyone attempting to reproduce using the code supplied in the question has to guess at the implementation.

Comment: @glytching I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the implementation of `ClassForTest`:

```
public static Boolean allowInternalLogging() {
    if (internalLogging == null) {
        try {
            internalLogging = inNetwork();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            internalLogging = false;
            LOGGER.debug("Could not determine logging granularity", e);
        }
    }
    return internalLogging;
}
```

This method effectively caches the result of `inNetwork` this has the effect of any subsequent calls reusing the result produced by the first call.

- If `test_nok` is called first it causes `ClassForTest.internalLogging` to be set to `false` thereby causing `test_is_ok` to fail because it expects `true`.
- If `test_is_ok` is called first it causes `ClassForTest.internalLogging` to be set to `true` thereby causing `test_nok` to fail because it expects `false`.

If you need to invoke this method multiple times and expect different results then you have to either reset `ClassForTest.internalLogging` between each invocation or somehow parameterise the `allowInternalLogging` method such that it can, optionally, bypass the cached value.

FWIW, I reproduced the issue using the code you supplied and then disabled the caching within `allowInternalLogging()` and on re-running both tests together they passed.

On a side note: the `inNetwork` method makes this call on `InetAddress`: `InetAddress.getByName("some-hostname-which-we-know");` but the test case you provided expects: `InetAddress.getLocalHost();` so there is a mismatch between the test case and the code-under-test.

Comment: Thanks so much! Indeed that is the case! I got lured by the mocking of the static class thinking it may have something to do with it.